# Creating a SQL Server table from a C# datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, datatable

I have a DataTable that I manually created and loaded with data using C#.

What would be the most efficient way to create a table in SQL Server 2005 that uses the columns and data in the DataTable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a little bit unusual in SQL to create tables out of a client supplied definition of a Datatable object. Tables are carefully crafted entities in SQL, with deploy time placement consideration of choosing the proper disk, with indexing consideration at design time and with all the issues involved in properly modeling a database.

Better you'd explain what you're trying to achieve so we understand what advice to give.

As a side note, in SQL 2008 there is a very easy way to create a table out of a client defined Datatable: pass the DataTable as a Table value parameter, then issue a `SELECT * INTO <tablename> FROM @tvp`, this will effectively transfer the definition of the Datatable *and* its content data into a real table in SQL.

Comment: +1 excellent tip with the TVF! Never thought of that feature in such a way :-) But as you say yourself - this will probably hardly ever be used in real life situations...

Comment: I'm looking forward to trying this out soon, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually, this is used a lot in a research stage of a project.  For instance, I am trying to import an old FoxPro database into SQL Server.  I am banging my head trying to tediously craft each and every column.  At the moment, getting that part right isn't important.  What's important is getting the data into the SQL Server where I can manipulate it more easily -- including figuring out how wide to make my string cols (right now, they are all varchar(max) while I see what's what.

Comment: Leonard Lobel wrote about [SQL Server 2K8 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/). As far as i understood the destination table must be already present in the database as well as a [user-defined table type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx). If this is no option for you the use of SQL Server Managment objects could be helpfull - see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17169/Copy-Data-from-a-DataTable-to-a-SQLServer-Database.

Comment: I have a feeling this solution defeats the purpose of automatic table creation. If you have to manually create the custom type, might as well create the table! I want to be able to have a piece of code that sniffs the table schema and creates a corresponding table to the best of its knowledge.

Comment: @DavidAirapetyan you are correct. Remus' tip with the tvp paramter would not work as you would have to define the table type *in advance* on database side which is exactly what the user is trying to solve.

Comment: Dapper code about pass the DataTable as a Table value parameter,  ?

Answer (score 73):

```
public static string CreateTABLE(string tableName, DataTable table)
{
    string sqlsc;
    sqlsc = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sqlsc += "\n [" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] ";
        string columnType = table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString();
        switch (columnType)
        {
            case "System.Int32":
                sqlsc += " int ";
                break;
            case "System.Int64":
                sqlsc += " bigint ";
                break;
            case "System.Int16":
                sqlsc += " smallint";
                break;
            case "System.Byte":
                sqlsc += " tinyint";
                break;
            case "System.Decimal":
                sqlsc += " decimal ";
                break;
            case "System.DateTime":
                sqlsc += " datetime ";
                break;
            case "System.String":
            default:
                sqlsc += string.Format(" nvarchar({0}) ", table.Columns[i].MaxLength == -1 ? "max" : table.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString());
                break;
        }
        if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
            sqlsc += " IDENTITY(" + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementSeed.ToString() + "," + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementStep.ToString() + ") ";
        if (!table.Columns[i].AllowDBNull)
            sqlsc += " NOT NULL ";
        sqlsc += ",";
    }
    return sqlsc.Substring(0,sqlsc.Length-1) + "\n)";
}
```

Comment: I believe this code (or some code reviewed approximation - why pass the connection if unused, why compare types with string comparison etc) is better than the accepted answer. Accepted answer won't work without defining the type of the table valued parameter on the server beforehand, which at least in my case defeats the point of being able to create the table just in time.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you had already used the SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema() on your DataTable and you're restoring a backup, you can use DataTable.TableName as the name and eliminate a parameter.

Comment: You have to multiply nvarchar size by 2. Otherwise you can experience truncation issues. I also avoid string.format inside loops for performance reasons. sqlsc += "nvarchar(" + (table.Columns[i].MaxLength == -1 || table.Columns[i].MaxLength > 4000 ? "max" : (table.Columns[i].MaxLength * 2).ToString()) + ")";

Comment: decimal loose precision and scale

Answer (score 18):

I know this question is rather old, but I just had something very similar that I needed to write. I took what I did and altered the examples provided by both Amin and rasputino and created an example that will output just the SQL. I added a few features and avoided concatenation to help improve upon a process that is inherently a poor performer.

```
/// <summary>
/// Inspects a DataTable and return a SQL string that can be used to CREATE a TABLE in SQL Server.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="table">System.Data.DataTable object to be inspected for building the SQL CREATE TABLE statement.</param>
/// <returns>String of SQL</returns>
public static string GetCreateTableSql(DataTable table)
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder alterSql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE [{0}] (", table.TableName);

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        bool isNumeric = false;
        bool usesColumnDefault = true;

        sql.AppendFormat("\n\t[{0}]", table.Columns[i].ColumnName);

        switch (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().ToUpper())
        {
            case "SYSTEM.INT16":
                sql.Append(" smallint");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.INT32":
                sql.Append(" int");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.INT64":
                sql.Append(" bigint");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.DATETIME":
                sql.Append(" datetime");
                usesColumnDefault = false;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.STRING":
                sql.AppendFormat(" nvarchar({0})", table.Columns[i].MaxLength);
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.SINGLE":
                sql.Append(" single");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.DOUBLE":
                sql.Append(" double");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.DECIMAL":
                sql.AppendFormat(" decimal(18, 6)");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            default:
                sql.AppendFormat(" nvarchar({0})", table.Columns[i].MaxLength);
                break;
        }

        if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
        {
            sql.AppendFormat(" IDENTITY({0},{1})", 
                table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementSeed, 
                table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementStep);
        }
        else
        {
            // DataColumns will add a blank DefaultValue for any AutoIncrement column. 
            // We only want to create an ALTER statement for those columns that are not set to AutoIncrement. 
            if (table.Columns[i].DefaultValue != null)
            {
                if (usesColumnDefault)
                {
                    if (isNumeric)
                    {
                        alterSql.AppendFormat("\nALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_{0}_{1}]  DEFAULT ({2}) FOR [{1}];", 
                            table.TableName, 
                            table.Columns[i].ColumnName, 
                            table.Columns[i].DefaultValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alterSql.AppendFormat("\nALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_{0}_{1}]  DEFAULT ('{2}') FOR [{1}];", 
                            table.TableName, 
                            table.Columns[i].ColumnName, 
                            table.Columns[i].DefaultValue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Default values on Date columns, e.g., "DateTime.Now" will not translate to SQL.
                    // This inspects the caption for a simple XML string to see if there is a SQL compliant default value, e.g., "GETDATE()".
                    try
                    {
                        System.Xml.XmlDocument xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

                        xml.LoadXml(table.Columns[i].Caption);

                        alterSql.AppendFormat("\nALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_{0}_{1}]  DEFAULT ({2}) FOR [{1}];", 
                            table.TableName, 
                            table.Columns[i].ColumnName, 
                            xml.GetElementsByTagName("defaultValue")[0].InnerText);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // Handle
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!table.Columns[i].AllowDBNull)
        {
            sql.Append(" NOT NULL");
        }

        sql.Append(",");
    }

    if (table.PrimaryKey.Length > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder primaryKeySql = new StringBuilder();

        primaryKeySql.AppendFormat("\n\tCONSTRAINT PK_{0} PRIMARY KEY (", table.TableName);

        for (int i = 0; i < table.PrimaryKey.Length; i++)
        {
            primaryKeySql.AppendFormat("{0},", table.PrimaryKey[i].ColumnName);
        }

        primaryKeySql.Remove(primaryKeySql.Length - 1, 1);
        primaryKeySql.Append(")");

        sql.Append(primaryKeySql);
    }
    else
    {
        sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    sql.AppendFormat("\n);\n{0}", alterSql.ToString());

    return sql.ToString();
}
```

Here's a simple test to use this method and get the SQL:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Users");

table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = "UserId",
    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
    AutoIncrement = true,
    AllowDBNull = false,
    AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
    AutoIncrementStep = 1
});

table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = "UserName",
    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String"),
    AllowDBNull = true,
    DefaultValue = String.Empty,
    MaxLength = 50
});

table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = "LastUpdate",
    DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"),
    AllowDBNull = false,
    DefaultValue = DateTime.Now, 
    Caption = "<defaultValue>GETDATE()</defaultValue>"
});

table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns[0] };

string sql = DataHelper.GetCreateTableSql(table);

Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

And finally, the output:

```
CREATE TABLE [Users] (
    [UserId] int IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] nvarchar(50),
    [LastUpdate] datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY (UserId)
);

ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Users_UserName]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [UserName];
ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Users_LastUpdate]  DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR[LastUpdate];
```

I agree with the original answer that states that data management isn't something that should be done haphazardly. It does indeed require a lot of thought to keep the DB running smoothly and allowing for maintainability in the future. But, there are times when a coding solution is necessary and I'm hoping this might help someone out.

Comment: just a couple of improvements for anyone looking at this (very good) solution:  
1. `SYSTEM.DOUBLE` type must be mapped to SQL Server's `float`  
2. when adding `DEFAULT` please check for empty (not null) values with `if (isNumeric && table.Columns[i].DefaultValue.ToString() != string.Empty)`

Answer (score 6):

Regarding Amin answer I added primary keys to his code.

```
public static string CreateTABLEPablo(string connectionString, string tableName, System.Data.DataTable table)
{
    string sqlsc;
    //using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        sqlsc = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sqlsc += "\n" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Int32"))
                sqlsc += " int ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.DateTime"))
                sqlsc += " datetime ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.String"))
                sqlsc += " nvarchar(" + table.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString() + ") ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Single"))
                sqlsc += " single ";
            else if (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().Contains("System.Double"))
                sqlsc += " double ";
            else
                sqlsc += " nvarchar(" + table.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString() + ") ";



            if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
                sqlsc += " IDENTITY(" + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementSeed.ToString() + "," + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementStep.ToString() + ") ";
            if (!table.Columns[i].AllowDBNull)
                sqlsc += " NOT NULL ";
            sqlsc += ",";
        }

        string pks = "\nCONSTRAINT PK_" + tableName + " PRIMARY KEY (";
        for (int i = 0; i < table.PrimaryKey.Length; i++)
        {
            pks += table.PrimaryKey[i].ColumnName + ",";
        }
        pks = pks.Substring(0, pks.Length - 1) + ")";

        sqlsc += pks;
        connection.Close();

    }
    return sqlsc + ")";
}
```

Comment: What if the table has no primary key? You will add a constraint with empty parenthesis (). Also, your constraint always adds a comma to the end of each column name, including the last one, which will break the SQL script.

Answer (score 6):

Here is some code that I have written to do just this thing for work. It has been tested and used in a production environment for script generation.
It handles `DBNull` and primary keys properly and does not fail if there are none or only one. It is also more performant than the other suggestions here because it uses `StringBuilder`, Linq's `Aggregate` and does not call `ToString()` repeatedly.

Note: If your data is coming from an external source, please make sure your code always sanitizes the input to this method or check the output of this method before blindly executing the generated script against your database.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a SQL script that creates a table where the columns matches that of the specified DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    public static string BuildCreateTableScript(DataTable Table)
    {
        if (!Helper.IsValidDatatable(Table, IgnoreZeroRows: true))
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE [{1}] ({0}   ", Environment.NewLine, Table.TableName);

        bool FirstTime = true;
        foreach (DataColumn column in Table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>())
        {
            if (FirstTime) FirstTime = false;
            else
                result.Append("   ,");

            result.AppendFormat("[{0}] {1} {2} {3}",
                column.ColumnName, // 0
                GetSQLTypeAsString(column.DataType), // 1
                column.AllowDBNull ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL", // 2
                Environment.NewLine // 3
            );
        }
        result.AppendFormat(") ON [PRIMARY]{0}GO{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine);

        // Build an ALTER TABLE script that adds keys to a table that already exists.
        if (Table.PrimaryKey.Length > 0)
            result.Append(BuildKeysScript(Table));

        return result.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds an ALTER TABLE script that adds a primary or composite key to a table that already exists.
    /// </summary>
    private static string BuildKeysScript(DataTable Table)
    {
        // Already checked by public method CreateTable. Un-comment if making the method public
        // if (Helper.IsValidDatatable(Table, IgnoreZeroRows: true)) return string.Empty;
        if (Table.PrimaryKey.Length < 1) return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        if (Table.PrimaryKey.Length == 1)
            result.AppendFormat("ALTER TABLE {1}{0}   ADD PRIMARY KEY ({2}){0}GO{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine, Table.TableName, Table.PrimaryKey[0].ColumnName);
        else
        {
            List<string> compositeKeys = Table.PrimaryKey.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName).ToList();
            string keyName = compositeKeys.Aggregate((a,b) => a + b);
            string keys = compositeKeys.Aggregate((a, b) => string.Format("{0}, {1}", a, b));
            result.AppendFormat("ALTER TABLE {1}{0}ADD CONSTRAINT pk_{3} PRIMARY KEY ({2}){0}GO{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine, Table.TableName, keys, keyName);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the SQL data type equivalent, as a string for use in SQL script generation methods.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetSQLTypeAsString(Type DataType)
    {
        switch (DataType.Name)
        {
            case "Boolean": return "[bit]";
            case "Char": return "[char]";
            case "SByte": return "[tinyint]";
            case "Int16": return "[smallint]";
            case "Int32": return "[int]";
            case "Int64": return "[bigint]";
            case "Byte": return "[tinyint] UNSIGNED";
            case "UInt16": return "[smallint] UNSIGNED";
            case "UInt32": return "[int] UNSIGNED";
            case "UInt64": return "[bigint] UNSIGNED";
            case "Single": return "[float]";
            case "Double": return "[double]";
            case "Decimal": return "[decimal]";
            case "DateTime": return "[datetime]";
            case "Guid": return "[uniqueidentifier]";
            case "Object": return "[variant]";
            case "String": return "[nvarchar](250)";
            default: return "[nvarchar](MAX)";
        }
    }
```

An example of the generated output:

```
CREATE TABLE [Order] (
   [OrderID] [bigint] UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
   ,[Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL 
   ,[Flag] [bit] NULL 
   ,[Quantity] [int] NULL 
   ,[Price] [decimal] NULL 
   ,[Customer] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE Order
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_OrderIDCustomer PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, Customer)
GO
```

Everything is included except for `Helper.IsValidDatatable()`, but you get the idea. This should at least be replaced by a null check and probably check against zero DataColumns.
In fact, if your curious, this code comes from a larger (but still under 1000 lines) open-source C# class library of mine that facilitates moving data from a C# class object to a DataTable, then to SQL scripts and back again. It also contains several helper data access methods for more succinct code. I call it EntityJustworks and it is where the body of the method IsValidDatatable() lives as well (In the Helper.cs class file). You can access the code either via CodePlex (https://entityjustworks.codeplex.com) or view a complete listing of all the other places (GitHub, Code.MSDN, Pastebin, ect) that EntityJustworks can be acquired by visiting its blog post (https://csharpcodewhisperer.blogspot.com/2015/01/entity-justworks-class-to-sql.html).

Answer (score 2):

How efficient do you need? I would probably write my own TSQL (based on the `DataTable`'s columns) to create the table + columns, but to fill it you have a choice; if you have a moderate number of rows, a [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) should be fine. If you have *lots* of data, then [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) accepts a `DataTable` and table name...

Comment: own TSQL (based on the DataTable's columns)  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean from any arbitrary ADO.Net DataTable, I think you'd have to code that as a DDL 'code generation' tool, iterating through the DataTables' columns collection as you construct the "Create Table... " DDL Statement.

Then connect to the desired database and execute the constructed Create Table DDL statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would just build a Create Table statement based on the DataTable and send that to Database. You can use SMO (SQL Server Managment objects) as well. Not sure what would be the fastest.

This is definitely something that could go into a framework level class for reuse.

The following link contains information (and code sample of a `SqlTableCreator`) on how to do this: [Creating a new table in SQL Server from ADO.NET DataTable](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/4929a0a8-0137-45f6-86e8-d11e220048c3). You can find forks of `SqlTableCreator` [here](https://gist.github.com/riyadparvez/4467819), [here](https://github.com/bobmarthin/Applenium/blob/master/WPFeToroAutoStudio/3%20-%20DAL/SqlTableCreator.cs), and [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/SqlTableCreator.cs).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I have written to do just this thing for work in progres sql.

```
int count = dataTable1.Columns.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
   if (i == count)
   {
       name += dataTable1.Columns[i].Caption + " VARCHAR(50)";
   }
   else
   {
       name += dataTable1.Columns[i].Caption + " VARCHAR(50)" + ", ";
   }
}

// Your SQL Command to create a table
string createString = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" + name + ")";                     
//SqlCommand create = new SqlCommand(createString, connection);
NpgsqlCommand create = new NpgsqlCommand(createString, connection);
connection.Open();
create.ExecuteNonQuery();
```