# Add collection as SQL parameter to SqlCommand without using (Table-Valued-Parameter) type

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, system.data

I'm trying to use a table as a parameter in my SQL query, but I cannot get it to work without using the name of an existing type (Table Valued Parameter).

In MSSQL I can do this:

```
declare @mytable table (column1 int, column2 nvarchar(10))
insert into @mytable select 1, "test" UNION ALL select 2, "test2" UNION ALL [...]

select * from sometable inner join @mytable on sometable.id = @mytable.column1
```

To accomplish this in C#, I can (roughly) do the following:

```
SqlCommand cmd ...
var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
p.TypeName = "MyType";                  // <-- I dont't want to do this
p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
p.Value = myDataTable;
p.ParameterName = "table";
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
cmd.CommandText = "select * from sometable inner join @mytable on ... ";
```

For this to work, I have to create the type "MyType" in the database: `CREATE TYPE [MyType] AS TABLE (...);`

My problem is that I need to explicitly specify the type of the table, even though in MSSQL I can do it inline (see previous example). Secondly, I need to explicitly define the type in the database for each possible collection type.

**Is there any way to add a collection as a parameter to the SQL command without needing to declare its type in the database and using that type as the type name of the parameter?**

Comment: Use a stored procedure and put code in SQL Server as a stored procedure.

Comment: Without a proc like @jdweng, suggested, you'll need to pass the collection as XML or JSON.

Comment: @jdweng (and Dan too) Thank you both for your quick replies; how would I go about doing that? I do not have the data in SQL server, so I have to supply it somehow.. And the only way of using stored procedures I can think of, uses the table valued parameter types..

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio which comes with SQL Server.  Create a Table for the data in SSMS Explorer.  Then create a stored procedure using.SSMS.

Comment: @jdweng But then I could just as well create a table and fill it with data, and use that table in my query, right? The thing is, I'm trying to find a way to dynamically use a collection of objects I have in my program in a query, without the need to specify its structure beforehand.

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046680/how-to-create-a-table-before-using-sqlbulkcopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Json (as proposed by @DanGuzman), tested it, and it performed more than well with a relatively simple dataset of about 500 items (my use case).

Simple implementation example in C#:

```
var col = new object[] { new { Column1 = "Test", Column2 = 1 }, new { Column1 = "2nd row", Column2 = 2 }, ... };
IDbDataParameter p = command.CreateParameter();
p.DbType = DbType.String;
p.ParameterName = "mytable";
p.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(col); // NewtonSoft 
command.Parameters.Add(p);
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@mytable) WITH (Column1 nvarchar(max), Column2 int)";
```

---

**References**:

- [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [JsonConvert.SerializeObject(..)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)