# Why doesn't DataSet create a new table in the database?

Tags: c#, database

I have a small problem with creating a new table in a database. I create a new table in my `DataSet` object, but this table is not created in the physical database. The table is created only in cache. Why?

My code:

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\Data.sdf");
SqlCeDataAdapter sCEdata = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from [Cats]", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sCEdata.Fill(ds);

DataColumn ID = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
ID.AllowDBNull = false;
ID.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
ID.AutoIncrement = true;
ID.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
ID.ReadOnly = true;
ID.Unique = true;
DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
DataColumn Owner = new DataColumn("Owner", typeof(string));
DataColumn Note = new DataColumn("Note", typeof(string));

DataTable Cats2 = new DataTable("Cats2");
Cats2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{ID, Name, Hozain, Note});

DataRow dr1 = Cats2.NewRow();
DataRow dr2 = Cats2.NewRow();
DataRow dr3 = Cats2.NewRow();
dr1["Name"] = "Pavel"; dr1["Owner"] = "Sergey"; dr1["Note"] = "Starii";
dr2["Name"] = "Gleb"; dr2["Owner"] = "Inga"; dr2["Note"] = "Tupaya";
dr3["Name"] = "Dusia"; dr3["Owner"] = "Olga"; dr3["Note"] = "Zlaya";

Cats2.Rows.Add(dr1); 
Cats2.Rows.Add(dr2); 
Cats2.Rows.Add(dr3);

dr2["Note"] = "Guzelle"; 

ds.Tables.Add(Cats2);

SqlCeCommandBuilder build = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(sCEdata); 

sCEdata.Update(ds);
```

Comment: Datasets don't do that.

Comment: how do you expect the database to know what you are creating without any valid Sql command also you are only doing a Select which returns data to an object not a Create ..where is the Create Table command..? I think you need to rethink your approach and write down the steps as to what you want to do.. also look up how to use the CreateTable command in sql

Comment: here is a good place to start reading @polyakov_s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348712/creating-a-sql-server-table-from-a-c-sharp-datatable

Comment: I think, DataAdapter updates physically database only using  DataSet object. For example, i adding, new rows in tables without using sql commands, and its worked. And sorry me, i am from Russia and bad wrote in english, but understand ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database only knows that is has to change something when you use a SQL command. You can create as many DataSets as you like, delete and insert data, but the Database stays the same until you tell it to change via a SQL command.