# Create table on DB along with data based on DataTable

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

In my C# code, I have get a DataTable from excel,It has somedata.Now I want to create a table in database using this DataTable ,and insert it's data to database.
How could I do it? using SqlBulkCopy?

I want to write a method like this

```
///using DataTable dt to create Table and insert data to this created table
public bool CreateTable(string sqlconnectionstring,DataTable dt)
{

}
```

Comment: This is bad practise  ! Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348712/creating-a-sql-server-table-from-a-c-sharp-datatable

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ImportTest 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ImportData.xls', [Sheet1$])
```