# Can I create table in MS SQL Express 2014 LocalDB using ADO.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, create-table, mssql-jdbc

I wrote a function that creates tables in MS SQL Server Express 2014. Here it is:

```
    private static void createAndAlterTables()
    {
        try
        {
            // Создать соединение с БД.
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
                    sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Выполняется создание таблиц", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    sqlCom.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AddedDevices](
                                          [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
                                          [ProfileId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
                                          [MountingLocation] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                                          [DeviceName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [DeviceDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                                          [OwnerCompany] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [StreetHouse] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                                          [LocalityRegion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                                          [Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [ZipCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [SwHwVersion] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [DeviceType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [SelectedInnerDiameter] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [SelectedBeamsQuantity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [SelectedExClass] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [PathToStorageFolder] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                                     CONSTRAINT [PK_AddedDevices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
                                          [Id] ASC
                                       )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
                                     ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]";
                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Таблица 'AddedDevices' успешно создана", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    //
                    sqlCom.CommandText = @"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AddedDevices] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AddedDevices_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]";
                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Таблица 'AddedDevices' успешно изменена", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    //
                    sqlCom.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeviceProfile](
                                          [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
                                          [DeviceName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
                                          [Brand] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                                          [DisplayedName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
                                          [RepositoryFileName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
                                          [RegistersQuantity] [int] NULL,
                                          [DeviceTypeCode] [int] NULL,
                                          [SerialNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
                                     CONSTRAINT [PK_DeviceProfile_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
                                          [Id] ASC
                                       )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
                                     ) ON [PRIMARY]";
                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Таблица 'DeviceProfile' успешно создана", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    //
                    sqlCom.CommandText = @"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DeviceProfile] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DeviceProfile_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]";
                    sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Таблица 'DeviceProfile' успешно изменена", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, "Ошибка при создании таблиц", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка при создании таблиц", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Если сбой транзакции:
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, "Ошибка при создании таблиц", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            else
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка при создании таблиц", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

When I connect to MS SQL Server Express 2014 and try to create table, then the result is successful. But when I connect to MS SQL Server Express LocalDB installed from prerequisite in InstallShield 2016 Premier (21 day trial), then tables are not created. Is there a reason in SQL Server type (Express and Express LocalDB)? Or I do anything wrong in my code. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The obvious answer is yes. Why are you asking? Do you get an error? An exception? Something? Post the *full* exception message, including the call stack. You can get that using `Exception.ToString`

Comment: And if there is no error, then how do you check the missing tables? Are you using DataDirectory in your connectionstring?

Comment: I do not use DataDirectory in my connectionstring.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, I ask because I must create tables in database on server but they are not created. Why? And I have no exceptions.

Comment: This is the connection string:   connectionString="Server=MY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=My_Database;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Comment: @Prohor that connection string is NOT a LocalDb one; this is a names sql express instance. How do you check that the tables are not there?

Comment: I bag you pardon I confused. This one is connection string: connectionString="Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=My_Database;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Comment: If you got no error, the tables have most probably been created. How, exactly, do you prove they haven't been created? Management Studio? Are you using the exact same instance name? Is there any code that forcibly recreates the database that you may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can create table directly from `C#` an `ADO.NET` please check [Some more example or things to remember when you create it from backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348712/creating-a-sql-server-table-from-a-c-sharp-datatable)

Here is an simple example of creating a table that has an `identity` column:-

```
private void btnDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection =
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);" +
              "Database='Exercise1';" +
              "Integrated Security=yes;"))
    {
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE StoreItems( " +
               "StoreItemID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, " +
               "Category varchar(50), " +
               "[Item Name] varchar(100) NOT NULL, " +
               "Size varchar(20), " +
               "[Unit Price] money);",
               connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("A new table named StoreItems has been crated.");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can accept this answer if this meet your requirement.@Prohor